# phpinfo still shows old PHP version after installing new version from source

Tags: opensuse, php, make, source, configure

I downloaded PHP 7.3.18 from [php.net](https://www.php.net/releases/). Then I configured it, maked it and installed it from source.

If I execute `php -v` then I get

> PHP 7.3.18 (cli) (built: Jun 17 2020 12:55:46) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
> 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.3.18, Copyright (c) 1998-2018
> Zend Technologies

but phpinfo shows 7.2.5

What am I missing?

Comment: I think I have to update Apache PHP instead, I currently ask how to do it here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593402/how-to-update-apache-php-version

Comment: I had to update the apache php version. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594364/124191