# openSuse - How to change apache php version?

Tags: apache-httpd, opensuse, php

I am currently on PHP 7.2.5 but I need 7.3.18. How can I update PHP for my Apache Webserver?

**OS (uname -a):**

> Linux linuxphp7 4.12.14-lp150.12.82-default #1 SMP Tue Nov 12 16:32:38
> UTC 2019 (c939e24) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Apache (httpd -v):**

> Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Linux/SUSE)
> Server built:   2018-03-26 14:17:24.000000000 +0000

---

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the php7 package (minor version) is bundled with the suse distribution. openSuse Leap 15.1 got php 7.2.x. openSuse Leap 15.2 got php 7.4.x. A SUSE distribution upgrade will upgrade php7 as well. php7.4 will be compatible with php7.3

Comment: @MichaelD., but I need a specific PHP version

Comment: why wouldn't it work with php7.4?

Comment: @MichaelD., because the software I use (magento 2) does not support it yet

Comment: No, they recommend php7.4 see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: @MichaelD., thats Magento 2.4 which is not released yet, we use 2.3.5-p1

Comment: The [devel repo](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php:/php73/openSUSE_Leap_15.1/) contains version 7.3.19 but not 7.3.18, so it's probably no solution?

Comment: @eblock, i can try 7.3.19, maybe it works

Comment: @eblock, what am i supposed to do now

Comment: You wrote you would try 7.3.19, did you? Was it successful?

Comment: @eblock, thats what the question is all about, i don't know how I can change the php version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try version 7.3.19 you have to add the respective repository:

```
zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php:/php73/openSUSE_Leap_15.1/ PHP7-test

zypper ref

zypper in apache2-mod_php7
```

This should install the newest available version, or you search for all versions before installing:

```
zypper se -s apache2-mod_php7
```

Please make sure to always backup your data before changing anything. To specify the desired version run:

```
zypper in apache2-mod_php7=7.3.19
```